# Spring Data JPA Named Native Queries pass Dynamic table name

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have repeated select query with exact same column but different Table/View name.
Is there any option to reduce the number of lines from my orm.xml file?

Example:

```
<named-native-query name="PeriodEntity.periodQuery.NA"
                    result-class="com.data.store.foundation.model.PeriodEntity">
    <query>
        SELECT
            LEVELNAME,
            TIME_SVC_LVL_OPR_DESC,
            TIME_SVC_LVL_NBR,
            CALENDARID,
            CHANNEL_KEY,
            ISCURRENT,
            PREVIOUS_CALENDARID,
            START_DT,
            ENDDATE,
            CXT,
            CAL_YEAR,
            ID,
            RANGE_DATE,
            LBL,
            SHORT_LABEL,
            FISCAL_YEAR
        FROM
            dbo.v_NRT_Time_Hier_RTL_FRCH
        WHERE
            Channel_key = :channelId
    </query>
</named-native-query>

<named-native-query name="PeriodEntity.periodQuery.EU"
                    result-class="com.data.store.foundation.model.PeriodEntity">
    <query>
        SELECT
            LEVELNAME,
            TIME_SVC_LVL_OPR_DESC,
            TIME_SVC_LVL_NBR,
            CALENDARID,
            CHANNEL_KEY,
            ISCURRENT,
            PREVIOUS_CALENDARID,
            START_DT,
            ENDDATE,
            CXT,
            CAL_YEAR,
            ID,
            RANGE_DATE,
            LBL,
            SHORT_LABEL,
            FISCAL_YEAR
        FROM
            dbo.v_Day_Time_Hier_RTL
        WHERE
            Channel_key = :channelId
    </query>
</named-native-query>
```

Note:

1. We are selecting only required columns from the table/view.
2. Can we declare a variable for all columns and use a variable name in the select query?
3. Can we provide the table/view name dynamically? So single <named-native-query name="PeriodEntity.periodQuery.**Generic**" will work for both?

Comment: If they are the same, and you pass the channelId why youu need two queries that do exacly the same?

Comment: But both quey has different View/Table name. I mean schema is the same but the table is different.

Answer (score 2):

JPA Named Queries are static, you cannot use a dynamic table name.

A couple of alternatives below. If you can alter the Java model, the first is preferable because it's based on a change that adapts the entities to your database, instead of adding complexity with dynamic queries.

### Option #1: Define abstract `PeriodEntity` and children

From your queries, it seems both tables `v_NRT_Time_Hier_RTL_FRCH` and `v_Day_Time_Hier_RTL` represent identical entities. You can define an abstract `PeriodEntity` class annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` and defining the shared attributes. Then define entities for each children that shares this structure.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PeriodEntity {
    @Column(name = "LEVELNAME")
    String levelName;

    @Column(name = "Channel_key")
    String channelKey;

    // etc.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "v_NRT_Time_Hier_RTL_FRCH")
public class NrtTimePeriodEntity extends PeriodEntity {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "v_Day_Time_Hier_RTL")
public class DayTimePeriodEntity extends PeriodEntity {
}
```

Your named native queries can then be replaced by non-native named queries, like: `SELECT T FROM DayTimePeriodEntity T WHERE channelKey = :channelId`.

From JPA 1.4.3, you can use a generic expression to refer to the entity name, and it will be replaced when the query is run: `SELECT T FROM #{#entityName} T ...`. That would let you go even further and define a single query for both entities.

### Option #2: "Dynamic" Native query

Another approach without changing your model is to define the Named Query in the code, moving it from the orm.xml to a custom method in a repository class. You can have any SQL and apply string processing to change the name of the table.

In your repository you would have something like:

```java
static final String SQL = "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE Channel_key = :channelId";

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

public List<PeriodEntity> findDayTimeByChannelId(String channelId) {
    String sql = SQL.replaceAll("<table>", v_Day_Time_Hier_RTL);
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, PeriodEntity.class);
    q.setParameter("channelId", channelId);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```